# how to convert formula to google spreadsheet using vlookup and array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formulas, gs-vlookup

How to convert from xcel vlookup to google webview.I have 2 files trying to link and lookup to same sheet and different sheet.

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,[range_lookup])
```

eg.

```
=VLOOKUP($C3,'[source_file_name.xlsx]source_sheet'!$A:$C,2,0)
```

for information c3 is in the destination source

hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The example includes a reference to an external file. Google Sheets works differently, you have first to import the external data by using [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).

Bear in mind that IMPORTRANGE requires the user authorization to access an external file, but the button to give this authorization is shown only when IMPORTRANGE is used non-nested `=IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key,reference_string)`.

Authorization is required only one time and could be given by the spreadsheet owner or any editor and will be valid while the file is owned by / shared with the user who gave the authorization.